# Vue-toastification - Augmenting Types in vuejs 3 with typescript is not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to use vue-toast-notification in my vue 3  project. The problem i am facing is vue Augmenting Types. I have seen the other answers and applied but its not working for me here is the error

```
TS2339: Property '$toast' does not exist on type 'Vue<unknown, {}, {}>'.
```

My Testing component from where i am trying to call the toast method

```
import { Vue } from "vue-class-component";
export default class Login extends Vue {

  private StoreID = "";
  private StorePassword = "";
  private errorMessage = "";
  testToast(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    const vm = new Vue()
   console.log(vm.$toast)
  }
}
```

My Tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "typings/vue.d.ts"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My vue.d.ts inside typings folders . typings folder is created on the root of the project where main.ts file exists.

```
// 1. Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueToast from 'vue-toast-notification';

// 2. Specify a file with the types you want to augment
//    Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
  interface Vue {
    $toast: VueToast
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the [latest version](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification/tree/next) using

```
npm install --save vue-toastification@next
```

Then try to add the following code to the main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Toast from 'vue-toast-notification';

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties  {
      $toast: Toast
      
     }
   }
let app=createApp(App)

app.use(Toast,{})

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: i tried the above and error is gone and rendering successfully but on browser console giving me a error

Comment: index.min.js?b079:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$toast' of undefined
    at Object.a.install (index.min.js?b079:1)
    at Object.use (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:2948)
    at eval (main.ts?bc82:34)
    at Module../src/main.ts (app.js:1381)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1598)
    at __webpack_require__

Comment: As I said this component doesn't support vue3

Answer (score 0):

```
 **yarn add vue-toastification@next**



  import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";
        
        data() {
            return {
                toast: useToast(),
        },
    methods:{
    async deleteStreams(id, index) {
          await $http.$delete("/admin/library/streams/" + id).then((response) => {
            if (response.success) {
              this.streams.splice(index, 1);
              this.toast.success("Deleted Successfully");
              return;
            }
            this.toast.error(response.message);
          });
        },
    
    }
```